# Is there a shortcut for switching open windows of the active application in OSX?

Tags: macos, shortcuts

When switching between applications it's quite common to press cmd+tab. That's a really easy and fast way to switch between different applications.

But I'm wondering, if there's a similar way to switch between the windows of the active application. For example, when I have 4-5 different LaTeX documents opened I want to switch between them as quickly as with cmd+tab.

Does anyone know a shortcut or an extension for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The shortcut you're looking for is <kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>`</kbd>.

[image]

Comment: awesome! that's exactly what I wanted to do - thank you!

Comment: Sorry if you did not like my edit.

Comment: Just found out, that you can edit this shortcut under keyboard preferences in the system preferences: "Move focus to the next window in application"