# Switching between windows of Same Applications ONLY for Spanish Layout (El Capitan OS X)

Tags: microsoft-word, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, osx-el-capitan, spanish

I open Word Office 2016 for MAC
Create Blank Document (Document1.docx) Add Text "Test One"
Create another Blank Document (Document2.docx) Add Text "Test Two"

Now I want change between Document1.docx and Document1.docx (only using 2 Keys, not function Keys)

I was reading these questions:

[In Mac OS, what is the keyboard shortcut to switch between windows of the same application?](https://superuser.com/questions/299241/in-mac-os-what-is-the-keyboard-shortcut-to-switch-between-windows-of-the-same-a/299242)

[Is there a shortcut for switching open windows of the active application in OSX?](https://superuser.com/questions/576912/is-there-ashortcut-for-switching-open-windows-of-the-active-application-in-osx?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I'm testing the before solutions but are not Working for me (Are not non english keyboard Questions).

My Questions is for Spanish Layout!

[image]

Here near picture!

[image]

<kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd> Is not working!

<kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd><</kbd> After changed still it is not working!

Here my Keyboards Image:

[image]
[image]

**How change between the before two documents using <kbd>⌘</kbd> + ?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Mac OS, what is the keyboard shortcut to switch between windows of the same application?](http://superuser.com/questions/299241/in-mac-os-what-is-the-keyboard-shortcut-to-switch-between-windows-of-the-same-a)

Comment: Like my question, there is not answer because not working, is the same layout for english?

Comment: What is the setting of the `Move focus to the next window` shortcut in the Keyboard system preference? Please [edit] your question to add a picture of the shortcut setting. The English keyboard default is `cmd+\``, but it may be different for a Spanish keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> is working well in my Spanish keyboard.

I use “Spanish ISO” layout because is the nearest one to my physical own. It’s *almost* the same to the one shown in the photos. The only difference is in the <kbd>ºª</kbd> key  (left to <kbd>1</kbd>, and the <kbd><></kbd> key (left to <kbd>Z</kbd>). Spanish ISO interchange their places (put <kbd>ª</kbd> (next to <kbd>Z</kbd>), and <kbd><</kbd> (next to 1)); it’s not a problem to me. The rest is exactly the same.

It works well with windows in Word and Excel. The solution could be changing the layout in Keyboard preferences. Long time ago I solved the way Office handle customized keyboards; it can happen in Mac.

Searching for “[Using custom keyboard layout in Word for Mac](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_mac-mso_mac2016/using-custom-keyboard-layout-in-word-for-mac/9ab0cca7-7b5e-4596-99bb-53d53edbc492)” in the internet could help. Sometimes “[Mac has wrong Spanish keyboard layout](https://superuser.com/questions/424763/)”.